# Elasticsearch match array usage

Tags: elasticsearch

is there a way to write a query that matches the empty array and any non empty array? I don't want to match nulls and I don't care for absent fields.

I just want to scan all my fields in order to see which ones can return an array.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The following query allows you to retrieve documents whose array field is not empty:

```
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": {
        "source": "doc.arr.value != null && doc.arr.size() > 0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that using `>=0` will also return documents with `null` arrays.

Detecting fields with an empty array is more complicated and cannot be achieved with a `script` query, because there's no different between an field containing an empty array and a field containing null.

A much better and more efficient way to achieve what you want is by adding a field at indexing time with the length of that array (e.g. called `arrayLength` below). That way you could use a simple [`range` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) on that field.

```
POST test/_search
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "arrayLength" : {
                "gte" : 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```