# Count of an Array within the ElasticSearch document

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have Elastic Index within the document there is Child Array. I need count of array across the document and count of an array for that particular index id.

Elastic Index looks like:

```
{
   "_index": "attach_info",
   "id": "AT23456",   
   "attachments": [
      {
         "type": "Attachment",
         "name": "txt.txt",
         "mimeType": "text/plain"
      },
      {
         "type": "Inline",
         "name": "jpg.jpg",
         "mimeType": "image/jpeg"
      }
   ]  
},

{
   "_index": "attach_info",
   "id": "AT23458",   
   "attachments": [
      {
         "type": "Attachment",
         "name": "txt.txt",
         "mimeType": "text/plain"
      },
      {
         "type": "Inline",
         "name": "jpg.jpg",
         "mimeType": "image/jpeg"
      },
      {
         "type": "Attachment",
         "name": "txt.txt",
         "mimeType": "text/plain"
      },
      
   ]  
}
```

---

- I need total count of an array "attachments" across document i.e. 5= (2+3)
- Also I need count of an array " attachments" w.r.t. individual index id i.e. id:AT23456 = count 2 and id:AT23456 = count 3

Comment: This has been answered before, here is a link to a thread that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57625462/4604579

Comment: @Val - Thanks for the response but it  didn't answered to my question.
Here I'm looking for the total count of particular Array Field (attachments) in the same doc id and total count of the Array Field (attachments) across the document.

Comment: It is, you can either use a script query/aggregation or (preferably) create a new integer field that contains the length of the array, then you can aggregate on that field